# how to upgrade from Linux mint 17.3 to Linux mint 18 without deleting any of your setting

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, settings

I would like to upgrade from Linux mint 17.3 to Linux mint 18. Is there a way to do this without deleting your settings, files, programs, bash_profile, etc. I know that you can back up files but can you import setting and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the tutorial posted on the official website to upgrade Linux mint 17 to 18 using `mintupgrade` tool or using the Linux-mint.iso:

1) [Using the mintupgrade tool](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2316)

Use the Backup Tool to backup your data.

1. Using the Update Manager, click on "Refresh" to refresh the APT cache and apply all level 1, 2 and 3 updates.
2. Give your terminal unlimited scrolling:

   Open a terminal.

   Click on "Edit"->"Profile Preferences"->"Scrolling".

   Check the "unlimited" option and click "OK".
3. Install the upgrade tool

   `apt install mintupgrade`
4. Check the upgrade

   `mintupgrade check`
5. Download the package upgrades:

   `mintupgrade download`
6. Apply the upgrades

   `mintupgrade upgrade`

2) Using the  live DVD Linux-mint 18 :

**[This tuto](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2)** explain how to upgrade your current version and how to restore your data and your software selection.

Comment: Does this back up your setting and bash profile and all added software